# pthread_join constantly causes segfault

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, distributed-computing

This issue is definitely the source of a stupid mistake, but for the life of me I cannot get to the bottom of it.

I'm writing a much larger program, but I've narrowed down a constant segfault error that is coming up whenever I call `pthread_join`. I've included the relevant code below, hopefully someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Cheers :)

**Functions for managing pthreads**

```c
void *scalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
  void *p;
  p = calloc(nmemb, size);
  if (p == NULL)
    sys_error("Error allocating memory block (calloc).", 1);
  return p;
}

pthread_t *new_thread_array(int n)
{
  return scalloc(n, sizeof(pthread_t));
}

int spthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
            void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)
{
  int ret;
  if ((ret = pthread_create(&thread, attr, start_routine, arg)) != 0)
    sys_error("Error at pthread_create.", ret);
  return 0;
}

int spthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval)
{
  int ret;
  if ((ret = pthread_join(thread, retval)) != 0)
    sys_error("Error at pthread_join.", ret);
  return 0;
}

int create_threads(pthread_t *thread_arr, int n, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
           void *(*start_routine) (void *), void **arg_arr)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    spthread_create(&thread_arr[i], attr, start_routine, arg_arr[i]);
    debug("created thread %d", i);
  }
  return 0;
}

int join_threads(pthread_t *thread_arr, int n, void **ret_arr)
{
  debug("Starting join");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (ret_arr != NULL)
      spthread_join(thread_arr[i], ret_arr[i]);
    else {
      debug("Attempting to join %d", i);
      spthread_join(thread_arr[i], NULL);
      debug("Joined %d", i);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Test code that produces the error**

```c
void *threadfunc(void *id)
{
  fflush(stdout);
  fprintf(stdout, "Thread %d printing.\n", *(int *)id);
  fflush(stdout);
  return;
}

int threadtest(int nodes)
{
  int ret;
  int *targs = scalloc(nodes, sizeof(int));
  int *pass[nodes];
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
    targs[i] = i;
    pass[i] = &targs[i];
  }

  printf("Starting L1 thread test...\n");
  pthread_t *threads = new_thread_array(nodes);
  debug("Allocated pthread array for %i threads.", nodes);

  create_threads(threads, nodes, NULL, &threadfunc, pass);
  join_threads(threads, nodes, NULL);
  debug("Successfully joined %i threads.", nodes);
  free(targs);
  free(threads);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  return threadtest(5);
}
```

Finally, here is the output of running the function `threadtest`, confirming that the segfault (appears) to occur in the parent thread, at the call to `pthread_join`.

```sh
Starting L1 thread test...
Allocated pthread array for 5 threads.
created thread 0
created thread 1
Thread 0 printing.
created thread 2
Thread 1 printing.
Thread 2 printing.
created thread 3
Thread 3 printing.
created thread 4
Thread 4 printing.
Starting join
Attempting to join 0
zsh: segmentation fault  ./tests/L1tests
```

Comment: Why is your thread proc lying when it claims it returns a `void*` when in fact is simply hard `return;` s ? I'm also at a loss as to why you're using a dynamic array for your `targs`, but a VLA for your `pass` sequences respectively. And though this isn't a [mcve], and it wouldn't be hard to make one by the looks of it. A proper set of `include`s, a real `main`, and providing the functions you chose for whatever reason not to include (ex:  `spthread_create`) etc.

Comment: @WhozCraig not including `spthread_create` was simply a mistake, I will update the example asap to include it. I will add the main function as well, though all it does is run the thread test function. Is there anything else I would be missing then? I was doing my best to provide a minimal reproducible example so I'm sorry it's not right.

Comment: @trenzafeeds That first issue is the cause. That's also the first warning gcc gives you.

Comment: @EmanuelP thank you, that was definitely an oversight on my part. Though gcc gives no error when compiling this with -Wall -Werror, and changing the return value of the function to be correct does not fix the segfault unfortunately.

Comment: This is also wrong: `pthread_create(&thread, attr, start_routine, arg)` and should scream warnings about further incompatible pointer types. In that context `thread` is already a pointer to `pthread_t`, therefore you're (a) passing the wrong type, and (b) not actually populating the `pthread_t` that `thread` actually pointed to before you blasted over it. And the `pass` argument is also invalid (at least type-wise) `void**` is not an opaque pointer type like the freewheel of `void*` . It is a *specific* type and should be honored.

Comment: @trenzafeeds Well, it does with mine. There's in fact a bunch of warnings that do that, but just returning NULL there solves the segfault. There's probably something in your build system that messes with the compiler flags.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you very much, it appears that misplayed & was the problem. Again though, gcc weirdly did not complain about it at all, and I double and triple checked that it was compiling with -Wall and -Werror

Comment: @EmanuelP yes probably I suppose, thank you. This is a real mess at the current time.